# Pass Object to Node JS GET request

Tags: node.js, angular, http

I am trying to pass an object to my NodeJS server from my angular application. I can read the object perfectly fine on the client-side, but not serverside.

Here is my client-side:

```
var query = {
  date: '9-2-2019',
  size: 4
}

this.http.get<any>(url, {params: {query: query} }).toPromise();
```

Why can I not pass this to my Node JS server?

```
No overload matches this call.
```

Is my error.

Comment: Please mention the full error message and nodejs web service code .

Comment: No overload matches this call.
Type '{ query: { date: string; size: number; }; }' is not assignable to type 'HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }'.

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Please change `{ params: {query: query}}` to be `{params: query}` and also change `query.size` to be string instead of number

```
var query = {
  date: '9-2-2019',
  size: '4'
}


this.http.get<any>(url, {params: query}).toPromise().then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(console.log);
```

Alternative

Create // utils.service.ts

```
import { HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
// ...
export class UtilsService {
    static buildQueryParams(source: Object): HttpParams {
        let target: HttpParams = new HttpParams();
        Object.keys(source).forEach((key: string) => {
      const value: string | number | boolean | Date = source[key];
            if ((typeof value !== 'undefined') && (value !== null)) {
                target = target.append(key, value.toString());
            }
        });
        return target;
    }
}
```

then use it in your service

```
import { UtilsService } from '/path/to/utils.service';

var query = {
  date: '9-2-2019',
  size: 4
}

 const queryParams: HttpParams = UtilsService.buildQueryParams(query);


this.http.get<any>(url, {params: queryParams }).toPromise().then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(console.log);
```

Comment: I just mis-copied it. It is closed now.

Comment: use then to send request or subscribe `this.http.get<any>(url, {params: {query: query} }).subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response);
  })`